# How to just audit if a Set of Entities change i.e. adding further entities to this Set (NOT the entity itself)

Tags: hibernate-envers

Person is an auditable Entity and is already annotated with @Audited.
One of the property is a Set of Address and this Set is annotated with @OneToMany.
The Address itself is a not auditable entity.
If I ever have to change the Set of Addresses by adding a new address (not the Address entity itself), I have to Audit in an other table called person_aud_addresses.
The table person_aud_addresses should hold the added address_id and the revision of the person from person_aud.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Audited
public class Person implements Serializable {
     .....
     @OneToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) //its not working because Address should not be auditable
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
     .....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_aud")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class PersonAud implements Serializable {   

    ....

    @OneToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Address implements Serializable {

    ....
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("addresses")
    private Person person;
    ....

}
```

Comment: Couple questions: 1) What's the significance of `CustomerProfile` here relative to your question? 2) Did you intend to write that you had an entity called `PersonAud` or `Person`?  3) What is the relationship between `Address` and `Person`?  Who owns it, is it bidirectional or unidirectional?

Comment: @Naros
1) I edited. I meant `Person`.

2). I have a `Person` Entity whose has a audit table called `PersonAud`.

3) Relationship between `Address` and `Person`: A Person owns a List of Adresses. But a Address belongs exact to a Person. (it is a bidirectional relationship)

Comment: I have an audit table called `person_aud_addresses`. This table is to be audited if the list of addresses from `person` changes.